# How to create a database object using MongoDB with Next.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js

I followed this tutorial to set up MongoDB in my Next.js application: https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/javascript/nextjs-with-mongodb.
In a file called mongodb-config.js, I have

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI
const options = {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
}

let client;
let dbPromise;

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Please add your Mongo URI to .env.local')
}


// In production mode, it's best to not use a global variable.
client = new MongoClient(uri, options)
dbPromise = client.connect()


// Export a module-scoped MongoClient promise. By doing this in a
// separate module, the client can be shared across functions.

export default dbPromise
```

The above is how I configure my database.

When I need to use the database for my API, I do:

```
import dbPromise from "database/mongodb-config";

let db;
dbPromise.then((value) => {
    const client = value;
    db = client.db("database_name");
})
.catch((error)=>{
    console.error(error);
});
```

db will be the variable that links to my database.

Now, I want to simplify this process and put everything in one file.

In the portion where I set up `dbPromise` in  mongodb-config.js, I initialize the `DB` variable and export it:

```
client = new MongoClient(uri, options)
dbPromise = client.connect()

let db;
dbPromise.then((value)=>{
    const client = value;
    db = client.db("datatbase_name");
})
.catch((error)=>{
  console.error(error);
});

export default db
```

I totally expect this to work. However, when I import db to another file and use it, the db is null. However, I waited until the `dbPromise` is resolved to pass `db` a value.

Comment: Catch should be in arrow function right ?

Comment: The `export` command is getting executed before the promise is resolved, that;s why it's null. Check it by logging `db` before and after `dbPromise.then`

Comment: @CharchitKapoor how can I force the export statement to wait for the promise to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `await` like this.

```
dbPromise = client.connect()

let db;
await dbPromise.then((value)=>{
    const client = value;
    db = client.db("datatbase_name");
})
.catch(error){
  console.error(error);
}

export default db
```

because mongoose is asynchronous so we have to use await before dbPromise otherwise `export` will be executed first before `dbPromise`.

Comment: I think you need to put await into an async function

Answer (score 0):

Try this, instead of returning `db`, return an async function, which you can all with `await`, in other parts to obtain, the connection to the database, the function will not try to make repeated connections, if they are already present:

```
let db, connection;
async function dbSetup() {
  try {
    if(!connection) {
       connection = await client.connect();
    }
    if(!db) {
       db = await connection.db("datatbase_name");
    }
    return db;
  } catch(error){
    console.error(error);
  }
}

export default dbSetup;
```

Another way is if you have node version 14.8 or greater, you can use top-level await functionality, which is basically using await, not inside an async function, like this:

```
client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
dbPromise = await client.connect();
let db = await dbPromise.db("datatbase_name");

export default db;
```

Comment: So you export a function that returns db. Each time you need to use DB, you will need to call the function. Is it possible to export db that's not null?